Is there a way to get the dates of the last N days, months, years in Python?
I would like to get the datetime objects for the last N days before today, each set to 0:00.
E.g., if today is November 18, 2024 and N = 3, then the expected result looks like:

24-11-17 0:00
24-11-16 0:00
24-11-15 0:00

The same with 3 latest month:

24-11-01 0:00
24-10-01 0:00
24-09-01 0:00

And 3 years:

24-01-01 0:00
23-01-01 0:00
22-01-01 0:00

It could be done completely manually, but I wonder if there is a Python library that can support it.
I tried to code, but didn't get the final idea
from datetime import datetime

timeStampToday = int(time.mktime(datetime.today().timetuple()))

for x in range(40, 0, -1):
    timeStampStart = timeStampToday - ( x)*24*60*60
    


You don't need a library. However, since you know you want a sequence of days, you don't need to subtract from the starting day each time. Two days ago is one day from one day ago; three days ago is one day from two days ago; etc.

Collecting days and years can be made with date and timedelta like from datetime import data, timedelta; days = [today - timedelta(days=n) for n in range(N)]; years = [date(date.today().year - n, 1, 1) for n in range(N)]. As of months, they can be produced in somewhat recursive way like months = (d:=date.today().replace(day=1)), *[(d:=(d - timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1)) for _ in range(N)] where you replace the day to 1, and for the previous date you move one day back from the current one and again replace the day to 1.
